# How should I prevent navbar collapse with content in React?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

When I open the navbar, the main page collapses along with it, as do the main page contexts on the navbar. I tried to use z-index, but it didn't work. I'm using tailwind in React; here's the code and an example:

[My code :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Uqe.png) 
[The result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txGgu.png)

How can I make the navigation bar appear at the top of each page?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand what you're asking. When you say "the main page collapses along with it" and "as do the main page context on the navbar", can you be more specific about what exactly is happening that you don't want to happen? Can you give a more complete description of what you are trying to accomplish in general?

Comment: @DragonBobZ I would like to do when I open navbar as shown second picture(The result) the text on the body "Let's face it...." it's above the navbar. It has to be like this example https://i.imgur.com/PnseXIx.png

Comment: That does look like a z-index problem. You need to make sure that the z-index on your nav bar is higher than the z-index of any content that is supposed to appear behind it. While you are trying to make this work, you can set the opacity on your sidebar such that no text can possibly be seen behind it so you know for sure whether your z-indexes are working as expected.

You said you already tried to use z-index and it didn't work. What did you try? If you can reproduce the problem in an easy to share format such as codepen or codesandbox, it's much easier to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @DragonBobZ I forgot to add "z-0" to other content. Now I give the z-10 navbar  it worked, thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome! Please upvote my comment :)

Comment: @DragonBobZI would like to, but I cannot do that. :'(

Comment: Okay, I added an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set z-index for both the sidebar and any content it should appear in front of. The navbar should have a higher z-index.